# Reset navigation stacks of all tabs in a Shell app

Tags: .net, tabs, maui, maui-shell

I have a iOS/Android .NET MAUI Shell app with Tabs where users can login.

I want to reset all tabs to the root element if a user logins in or out of my app, but I can't find a way to do it.

Is there a way in .NET MAUI Shell to retrieve the navigation stack of all tabs, so I can pop all pages?

Or any other idea how to reset all Tabs to the root page?

Comment: For other readers, it would be useful to provide more context, especially some code that shows what you're dealing with. Because of the lack of this, I have provided a more generic answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reset each Tab's navigation stack individually is to call `PopToRootAsync()` on each. For this you need to give each Tab a name:

```xml
<TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar">
    <Tab x:Name="Tab1">
        <ShellContent />
    </Tab>
    <Tab x:Name="Tab2">
        <ShellContent />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Then call `PopToRootAsync()` on each navigation stack in the code-behind of your AppShell:

```cs
await Tab1.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
await Tab2.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

This can be simplified if you give your TabBar an `x:Name` and then iterate through the `Items` and call `PopToRootAsync()` on each:

```cs
foreach(var tab in MyTabBar.Items)
{
    await tab.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
}
```

Alternatively, you can also reset the `MainPage` to a new instance of `AppShell` in your App.xaml.cs:

```cs
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

This is a common scenario when login pages are not part of the Shell hierarchy, but should also work in your case.